# Converting d3.js TopoJSON map from v3 to v5

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3.js map that I've been converting from using geoJSON and D3.js v3, to topoJSON and D3.js v5. The map is drawing correctly but there's something wrong with how data is applied to each country in the map, so that it's not available for mouseover, click, etc.

```js
const svg = container
  .append("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);

const projection = d3
  .geoMercator()
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
  .scale(100)
  .center([0, 40]);

const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

const countries = topojson.feature(
  topojsonData,
  topojsonData.objects.ne_50m_admin_0_countries
);

svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(countries.features)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", onClick);

var onClick = function (event, d) {
  console.log(d);
};
```

Clicking a country only logs integers like `202` or `16`.

I've read the v4 changelog but don't understand if/how [the changes to selections](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection) affects what I'm doing, of if it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler than I expected. I just needed to change the arguments for `onClick()` and the other similar event handlers:

```js
var onClick = function (d, i) {
  console.log(d);
};
```